# Networkmanager nmcli con modify overwrites configuration in /etc/NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager

I have used nmcli to import an ovpn configuration file and it does this correctly:

```bash
nmcli connection import type openvpn file mycon.ovpn
```

Connection 'mycon' (7ca383e3-ade9-4a8b-9402-16a93cd8f0e8) successfully added

When I inspect the connection afterwards through the GUI, everything seems correct.

This file does not contain a username, so I try to update the connection with the modify command:

```bash
nmcli connection modify mycon vpn.data username="myuser"
```

This command also succeeds, only, when I now look at the configuration file in '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mycon.nmconnection' I can see that the whole [vpn] section was completely overwritten:

```
[vpn]
username=myuser
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
```

As far as I can see in the documentation of nmcli, this is not supposed to happen.

System details:

```
❯ neofetch --off
xxxxx@ganymede 
--------------- 
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 6.4.6-76060406-generic 
Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
DE: GNOME 42.5 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Pop 
Terminal: gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you use set a unique value "username":

```
nmcli connection modify mycon vpn.data username="myuser"
```

which overrides the whole content of the setting.

To upsert a value in your parameter, you should prefix the field name by a plus sign, like this:

```
nmcli connection modify mycon +vpn.data username="myuser"
```

Regards,
Fabian

> More details about the command in the section 3.3.8 of [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_ip_networking_with_nmcli#sec-Adding_and_Configuring_a_Static_Ethernet_Connection_with_nmcli).

Comment: Thanks, the documentation should mention this. I have not seen that.